# Retrieve user input to display content from a button?

Tags: javascript, html

my HTML & CSS code

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <label for="bodyInput">Body Text: </label><input id="bodyInput" type="text"><br>
    <label for="qtyInput">Quantity: </label><input id="qtyInput" type="text"><br>
    <label for="colorInput">Color: </label>
    <select id="colorInput">
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select><br>

    <button id="runBtn">Display Content</button>
    <button id="resetBtn">Clear Content</button>

    <h2>Results</h2>
    <div id="resultsWrapper"></div>
</div>
<style>
#wrapper {
        background-color: #fff;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px 40px;
    }
    #resultsWrapper .result {
        border: 4px solid red;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
    #resultsWrapper .red {
        border-color: red;
    }
    #resultsWrapper .red h2 {
        color: red;
    }
    #resultsWrapper .green {
        border-color: green;
    }
    #resultsWrapper .green h2 {
        color: green;
    }
    #resultsWrapper .blue {
        border-color: blue;
    }
    #resultsWrapper .blue h2 {
        color: blue;
    }
 </style>
```

In bodyInput, I'm planning on displaying a box of content from the user, and in qtyInput, I'm displaying said box of content X number of times. The image below should be the result of the javascript functioning.

[Mock up results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSd1S.jpg)

Here's what I put so far, but I'm aiming to do this purely on its own, without external javascript libraries.

```
(function(){
        var bodInp = document.getElementById('bodyInput').value;
        var qtyInp = document.getElementById('qtyInput').value;
        var colorInp = document.getElementById('colorInput');
        var colSelect = colorInp.options[colorInp.selectedIndex].changeColor;


        qtyInp = Number(qtyInp.value);
        document.getElementById('resetBtn').addEventListener('click', reset, false);
        document.getElementById('runBtn').addEventListener('click',runLab, false);
        document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click',test,false);


        function test(){ // Couldn't find the values when I launched it.. they were undefined despite putting in some text & numbers.
            console.log('bodInp');
            console.log('qtyInp');
            console.log(colorInp.value);
        }

        function reset(){

            document.getElementById('bodInput').value="";
            document.getElementById('qtyInput').value="";
            colorInp.value = colorInp.options[colSelect].text;
        }

        function runLab(){
            colorInp.changeColor=colSelect;
        }




    })();
```

**Edit** - Answer was not entirely resolved, but put on the right path. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach onclick events to the buttons directly into the HTML of the buttons

```
<button id="runBtn" onclick="test()">Display Content</button>
```

Then you need to get the value of the inputs when the button is clicked. The way you wrote it they are picked up when the page is loaded (at which time the input boxes are still empty).

```
function test() {

  // get the current value of bodyInput at the time the button is clicked
  var bodInp = document.getElementById('bodyInput').value;

  // the value of a text box is a string which has a conversion function
  var qtyInp = document.getElementById('qtyInput').value.parseInt();

  // hold the target content in an array
  var content = [];

  // add the content in a for loop
  for (var i=0; i<qtyInp; i++) {
    content.push("<div>"+bodInp+"</div>");
  }

  // join the result and put it into the target div
  document.getElementById("resultsWrapper").innerHTML = content.join("");
}
```

Comment: I thought event listeners would take the information after the user would input it. Is there a way to take the value after a person puts in data? Thanks.

Comment: The event listeners call a function at the time of the event which can then access the current state of the document, i.e. read out the current value of a textbox via the document.getElementById function. When you assign the value of a textbox to a variable, the variable does not change when the textbox changes.

Comment: I don't quite understand the *var content =[];* part. Can you explain what's going on there and why I need the content.join() from the innerHTML?

Comment: You can use string variable and append the content
var content = ""; content += "abc";
but if you do not know how large the content will get an array that you later join is more efficient that keeping to append to a string. Its probably overkill in your case though.